# Editing a video online

Tags: webapp-rec

How can I go about making edits to an online video without having to download it and/or an application to my desktop?

I want to be able to edit a video using a web-based service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/editor) ? See here more details: http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/16/youtube-video-editor/
2. [stashSpace](http://www.stashspace.com/video-editing/online-video-editor.stm)

There were a couple more, but they were either bought ([Motionbox](http://www.motionbox.com/) by HP, Jumpcut by Yahoo) or vanished (eyespot - I say that because I can't access their web page). And I think photobucket has a feature like this, but I'm not sure.